# Populate Fields in Google Sheets Based on Cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

Is it possible to have a bunch of other cells' content modified if a cell's content matches a specific format?

e.g. I enter in "ABC,15" into one cell then a certain number of neighbor cells (depending on a formula) get highlighted.

Edit: The cell I enter "ABC, 15" is not static, it is arbitrary.

So,

e.g.

Let's say I've got three rows:

X X X X X X X X X X

X X X X X X X X X X

X X X X X X X X X X

Then Y's content changes (Y="ABC,15")

X X X X X X X X X X

X X **Y** X X X X X X X

X X X X X X X X X X

Some formula, whose input is "ABC,15", figures out how many of Y's right neighbors' content and style to change:

X X X X X X X X X X

X X **Y** **X X X X** X X X

X X X X X X X X X X

Then I decide I want 8, not 15.. maybe this happens:

X X X X X X X X X X

X X **Y** **X X** X X X X X

X X X X X X X X X X

I could have selected *any* initial "X" as the "Y". It might happen that after these tries, I select a different "Y", completely, and use "XYZ,35". Thought is that conditional formatting would get too complex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Google App Script for Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets) is what I was looking for. Though, it wasn't obvious to get to that point.

Answer (score 1):

That is a feature called conditional formatting. It is build into Google Spreadsheet.

Here is the google documentation (it is not exhaustive unfortunately):
https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413?hl=en

This is a spreadsheet that shows you multiple ways to use condional formatting.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ScDqtZvhsmf2iByAuxHBu0-ESpX_TE5pdtBvAxOJ99E/edit#gid=0